# Can I substitute $\beta A \alpha^{1-\gamma}$ with $c^\gamma$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I reach a point where in the book the author substitutes $\beta A \alpha^{1-\gamma}$ with $c^\gamma$ to simplify the rest of notation, where $\beta, \gamma \in (0,1)$ and $\alpha, A$ two other positive numbers. Is this generally possible, independently of the values of the coefficients?

I can obviously understand the substitution  $\beta^\gamma A^\gamma \alpha^{\gamma} = c^\gamma$, but not this.

I would guess that the reasoning is something like:
$$ \beta A \alpha^{1-\gamma} = e^{\ln \beta} e^{\ln A} e^{\ln \alpha} e^{\ln \alpha^\gamma} = e^{\ln \beta} e^{\ln A} e^{\ln \alpha} e^{\gamma\ln \alpha}  = e^{\ln \beta + \ln A +\ln \alpha} e^{\gamma\ln \alpha} = \delta e^{\gamma\ln \alpha} 
$$
but then?

Comment: Likely the (admittedly unfortunate) notation $c^\gamma$ is not intended to be read as exponentiation — think of it as $c(\gamma)$ where $c\colon\;\gamma\mapsto\beta A\alpha^{1-\gamma}$ is a function.

Comment: Maybe more context would help. I guess that the substitution is $\beta A\alpha^{1−\gamma}$ to $D\cdot c^{\gamma}$.

Comment: Dang sorry I think I have a major facepalm moment again. I think it is solved with
$(\sqrt{\beta})^\gamma  (\sqrt{A})^\gamma (\sqrt{\alpha})^\gamma \alpha^\gamma = (\sqrt{\beta} \sqrt{A} \sqrt{\alpha}  \alpha)^\gamma = c^\gamma $ , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following
$$\beta A \alpha^{1-\gamma}=((\beta A \alpha^{1-\gamma})^{1/\gamma})^\gamma=(\beta^{1/\gamma}A^{1/\gamma}\alpha^{(1/\gamma)-1})^\gamma=c^\gamma$$
so that
$$c=\beta^{1/\gamma}A^{1/\gamma}\alpha^{(1/\gamma)-1}$$